# Unable to decode valid base64 string swift

Tags: swift, base64

I've generated a PDF with jsPDF and it results in this dataURL:

```
data:application/pdf;filename=generated.pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKJbrfrOAKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQgMSAwIFIKL1Jlc291cmNlcyAyIDAgUgovTWVkaWFCb3ggWzAgMCA1OTUuMjggODQxLjg5XQovQ29udGVudHMgNCAwIFIKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwKL0xlbmd0aCA3Mwo+PgpzdHJlYW0KMC41NyB3CjAgRwpCVAovRjEgMTYgVGYKMTguNDAgVEwKMCBnCjU2LjY5IDc4NS4yMCBUZAooSGVsbG8gd29ybGQhKSBUagpFVAplbmRzdHJlYW0KZW5kb2JqCjEgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvUGFnZXMKL0tpZHMgWzMgMCBSIF0KL0NvdW50IDEKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjUgMCBvYmoKPDwKL1R5cGUgL0ZvbnQKL0Jhc2VGb250IC9IZWx2ZXRpY2EKL1N1YnR5cGUgL1R5cGUxCi9FbmNvZGluZyAvV2luQW5zaUVuY29kaW5nCi9GaXJzdENoYXIgMzIKL0xhc3RDaGFyIDI1NQo+PgplbmRvYmoKNiAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvRm9udAovQmFzZUZvbnQgL0hlbHZldGljYS1Cb2xkCi9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQovRW5jb2RpbmcgL1dpbkFuc2lFbmNvZGluZwovRmlyc3RDaGFyIDMyCi9MYXN0Q2hhciAyNTUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjcgMCBvYmoKPDwKL1R5cGUgL0ZvbnQKL0Jhc2VGb250IC9IZWx2ZXRpY2EtT2JsaXF1ZQovU3VidHlwZSAvVHlwZTEKL0VuY29kaW5nIC9XaW5BbnNpRW5jb2RpbmcKL0ZpcnN0Q2hhciAzMgovTGFzdENoYXIgMjU1Cj4+CmVuZG9iago4IDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9UeXBlIC9Gb250Ci9CYXNlRm9udCAvSGVsdmV0aWNhLUJvbGRPYmxpcXVlCi9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQovRW5jb2RpbmcgL1dpbkFuc2lFbmNvZGluZwovRmlyc3RDaGFyIDMyCi9MYXN0Q2hhciAyNTUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjkgMCBvYmoKPDwKL1R5cGUgL0ZvbnQKL0Jhc2VGb250IC9Db3VyaWVyCi9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQovRW5jb2RpbmcgL1dpbkFuc2lFbmNvZGluZwovRmlyc3RDaGFyIDMyCi9MYXN0Q2hhciAyNTUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjEwIDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9UeXBlIC9Gb250Ci9CYXNlRm9udCAvQ291cmllci1Cb2xkCi9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQovRW5jb2RpbmcgL1dpbkFuc2lFbmNvZGluZwovRmlyc3RDaGFyIDMyCi9MYXN0Q2hhciAyNTUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjExIDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9UeXBlIC9Gb250Ci9CYXNlRm9udCAvQ291cmllci1PYmxpcXVlCi9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQovRW5jb2RpbmcgL1dpbkFuc2lFbmNvZGluZwovRmlyc3RDaGFyIDMyCi9MYXN0Q2hhciAyNTUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjEyIDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9UeXBlIC9Gb250Ci9CYXNlRm9udCAvQ291cmllci1Cb2xkT2JsaXF1ZQovU3VidHlwZSAvVHlwZTEKL0VuY29kaW5nIC9XaW5BbnNpRW5jb2RpbmcKL0ZpcnN0Q2hhciAzMgovTGFzdENoYXIgMjU1Cj4+CmVuZG9iagoxMyAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvRm9udAovQmFzZUZvbnQgL1RpbWVzLVJvbWFuCi9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQovRW5jb2RpbmcgL1dpbkFuc2lFbmNvZGluZwovRmlyc3RDaGFyIDMyCi9MYXN0Q2hhciAyNTUKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjE0IDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9UeXBlIC9Gb250Ci9CYXNlRm9udCAvVGltZXMtQm9sZAovU3VidHlwZSAvVHlwZTEKL0VuY29kaW5nIC9XaW5BbnNpRW5jb2RpbmcKL0ZpcnN0Q2hhciAzMgovTGFzdENoYXIgMjU1Cj4+CmVuZG9iagoxNSAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvRm9udAovQmFzZUZvbnQgL1RpbWVzLUl0YWxpYwovU3VidHlwZSAvVHlwZTEKL0VuY29kaW5nIC9XaW5BbnNpRW5jb2RpbmcKL0ZpcnN0Q2hhciAzMgovTGFzdENoYXIgMjU1Cj4+CmVuZG9iagoxNiAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvRm9udAovQmFzZUZvbnQgL1RpbWVzLUJvbGRJdGFsaWMKL1N1YnR5cGUgL1R5cGUxCi9FbmNvZGluZyAvV2luQW5zaUVuY29kaW5nCi9GaXJzdENoYXIgMzIKL0xhc3RDaGFyIDI1NQo+PgplbmRvYmoKMTcgMCBvYmoKPDwKL1R5cGUgL0ZvbnQKL0Jhc2VGb250IC9aYXBmRGluZ2JhdHMKL1N1YnR5cGUgL1R5cGUxCi9GaXJzdENoYXIgMzIKL0xhc3RDaGFyIDI1NQo+PgplbmRvYmoKMTggMCBvYmoKPDwKL1R5cGUgL0ZvbnQKL0Jhc2VGb250IC9TeW1ib2wKL1N1YnR5cGUgL1R5cGUxCi9GaXJzdENoYXIgMzIKL0xhc3RDaGFyIDI1NQo+PgplbmRvYmoKMiAwIG9iago8PAovUHJvY1NldCBbL1BERiAvVGV4dCAvSW1hZ2VCIC9JbWFnZUMgL0ltYWdlSV0KL0ZvbnQgPDwKL0YxIDUgMCBSCi9GMiA2IDAgUgovRjMgNyAwIFIKL0Y0IDggMCBSCi9GNSA5IDAgUgovRjYgMTAgMCBSCi9GNyAxMSAwIFIKL0Y4IDEyIDAgUgovRjkgMTMgMCBSCi9GMTAgMTQgMCBSCi9GMTEgMTUgMCBSCi9GMTIgMTYgMCBSCi9GMTMgMTcgMCBSCi9GMTQgMTggMCBSCj4+Ci9YT2JqZWN0IDw8Cj4+Cj4+CmVuZG9iagoxOSAwIG9iago8PAovUHJvZHVjZXIgKGpzUERGIDEuNS4zKQovQ3JlYXRpb25EYXRlIChEOjIwMTkwMTE4MTQyNDQxKzAxJzAwJykKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjIwIDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9UeXBlIC9DYXRhbG9nCi9QYWdlcyAxIDAgUgovT3BlbkFjdGlvbiBbMyAwIFIgL0ZpdEggbnVsbF0KL1BhZ2VMYXlvdXQgL09uZUNvbHVtbgo+PgplbmRvYmoKeHJlZgowIDIxCjAwMDAwMDAwMDAgNjU1MzUgZiAKMDAwMDAwMDI0NyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAyMDY0IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDAwMTUgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDEyNCAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwMzA0IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDA0MjkgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDU1OSAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwNjkyIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDA4MjkgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDk1MiAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAxMDgxIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDEyMTMgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMTM0OSAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAxNDc3IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDE2MDQgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMTczMyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAxODY2IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDE5NjggMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMjMxMiAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAyMzk4IDAwMDAwIG4gCnRyYWlsZXIKPDwKL1NpemUgMjEKL1Jvb3QgMjAgMCBSCi9JbmZvIDE5IDAgUgovSUQgWyA8QTY4MzdFOTVEMjNDNTYxOEM0MTdFQ0UyMzRDNzI2OEE+IDxBNjgzN0U5NUQyM0M1N
```

But I'm not able to decode the base64 string in Swift 4.

Several online tools are perfectly able to decode the string, Safari is able to open the URL, but Swift is not able to decode it this way:

```
let base64Encoded = "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"
let decodeData = Data(base64Encoded: base64Encoded, options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
```

I read solutions about padding the string, but I'm not able to decode the string even if = characters are added to make the character count a multiple of 4. What is wrong with the base64 string or my code?

Comment: Padding your `base64Encoded` string to "JVBERi0xLjMKJbrfrOAKMyA=" makes it decode without problems ...

Comment: The final "N" seems to be wrong. If you remove that then it decodes properly.

Comment: This string is 4045 characters long, which is one more than a multiple of 4, which is impossible for Base64. I suspect your data is truncated. If you remove the last `N`, it will decode, which is what I suspect your online tests are doing.

Comment: When I decode this data with the command-line `base64`, the resulting PDF is corrupted and ends in the middle of a command. I'm pretty certain this is just truncated data. Your entire dataURL is exactly 4096 bytes, which just happens to be a very common buffer size and an extremely common block size for network and disk-I/O data.

Comment: If you compare it with an online decoder then note that PDF files should end with `%%EOF` .

Comment: FYI - once you work out why the base64 encoded part is incorrect, note that the full string is a special `data` URL. You can create a `URL` from the full string and then use `Data(contentsOfURL:)` to convert the URL into the decoded data.